# PHP redirect user to personal page

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I want to redirect a user to specific page with their user name (which will I manually create)
so when user2 logs in it will redirect them to user2.php, when user1 logs in it will redirect them to user1.php. 
I will manualy create the user page from their username after registering.

This is what I use but it redirects every user to the same page (except admin)

```
if ( IsUserConnected() ) {
    if (IsUserAuthorized($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header('Location: /username.php');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are redirecting all users to `username.php` .

Do this instead :

```
if ( IsUserConnected() ) {
    if (IsUserAuthorized($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header('Location:/'.$_SESSION['username'].'.php');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Added `header('Location: /'.$_SESSION['username'].'.php');`

```
if ( IsUserConnected() ) {
    if (IsUserAuthorized($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header('Location: /'.$_SESSION['username'].'.php');
        exit();
    }   
}
```

Comment: that is what I said earlier @Krish :)

Comment: @Alireza Fallah, You have not mentioned the `.php` extension previously and also to add `exit()` after header location

Comment: exit is not necessary every where

Comment: @Alireza Fallah, Generally, it is good practice to add `exit();`

Comment: @Alireza Fallah , ofcourse it is not problem!, but it is practice :)

Comment: Im agree :) I have nothing to say :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change the third line to

```
header("Location: /path/" . $_SESSION['username'] . ".php");
```